# Image upload does not render properly on Safari on Macbook Air built in display

Tags: bug, safari, image-upload

The Macbook air builtin display has a resolution of 1366x768. The vertical resolution is too low to see the bottom of the image upload widget preventing me from clicking the upload picture button.

[image]

Comment: It's nothing to do with the resolution. It's the browser not supporting the `transform` property which is needed to center the dialog correctly. Which browser version are you using?

Comment: I kinda like this; you get to see most of what you're writing while uploading. If only you could pick and choose Safari bugs.

Comment: It centers correctly for me in Safari, @animuson, even when I make the window very small. And that's way back on Safari 9.1.3.